# Connecting a docker container to a mongoDB container on another computer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, express

I have an application with 3 different containers, 2 of these containers are located on the same machine, a server container which holds my express server and a mongoDB container for the database, which have no issue talking to each other since they are linked throught docker-compose, however I have a third container which runs on a different computer but should also talk to the database container, but when i try connecting to the Database using `"mongodb://{IPAddress}:27017/"` the connection fails, I can use the same ip from outside of the container to connect, but once the app is containerized the connection fails.

I read up and some people recommended using `-net=host` when running my docker container. but I have to use windows containers and the host network is not supported on windows containers.

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: Have you mapped the 27017 port into the container? `docker run -p 27017:27017 mongo`

Comment: @Matt Yeah, the MongoDB container is mapped correctly, when i try to access directly, using MongoDB Compass or similar solutions, it works great, and when i try to access it from the app outside of the docker container it connects without a hitch, it's when i dockerize the app that the connection fails.